# How to stop client error with redux saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Can't stop infinity loop client error like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yubj0.jpg

This error just typo.
But saga action is repeated endless times.
When I tried without saga, I got only one time error. (Not endless)

I made sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-pine-qvcyv?from-embed

saga:

```js
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* fetchSome(action: Action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api, { id });
    yield put(fetchSomeSucess({ data }));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(fetchSomeFailure(e));
  }
}

export function* someProcess() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_SOME', fetchSome);
}
```

store:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { rootReducer } from '../reducers';
import { rootSaga } from '../sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const runSaga = async () => {
  return sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
};

export const configureStore = (initialState: Object = {}) => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
  );
  runSaga();
  return store;
};
```

rootSaga:

```js
import { all, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(someProcess),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your action creators are using the right constants.  In this file:

```
function* fetchSome(action: Action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api, { id });

    yield put(fetchSomeSucess({ data }));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(fetchSomeFailure(e));
  }
}
```

You need to make sure that the `fetchSomeSucess()` and `fetchSomeFailure()` action creators are not creating an action with `type: FETCH_SOME` which could easily be a typo.

If either of those have `type: FETCH_SOME` it would continually call your saga creating an endless loop

Comment: type name is correct.
Just variable is typo like: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-pine-qvcyv?from-embed

Comment: Then fix the typo